# como executar um botão especifico numa lista de 5 botões identicos

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, javascript-eventos

Estou a fazer uma dashboard com utilizadores e preciso de um botão editar.
Quando o botão editar é executado ele apenas faz aparecer e desaparecer código, mas queria saber se é possível executar código jQuery e seleccionar o id do botão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<a id="1" class="edit">E</a>
<a id="2" class="edit">E</a>
<a id="3" class="edit">E</a>

$('.edit').on('click',function(){
    var id = $('.edit').id;
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Esse html está mal formatado `<a id="1"edit">` ... o `edit` é uma classe?

Comment: @Sergio peço desculpa sim é uma class="edit" e no jquery falta o '.edit'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O teu html `<a id="1"edit">E</a>` está mal formatado, mas partindo do principio que o teu seletor funciona, dentro da callback do jQuery podes usar `this.id` para saber o ID do elemento que originou o evento.

```
$('a.edit').on('click',function(){
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado. :D

Answer (score 0):

Terás que adicionar uma class às tuas `a`nchor tags, assim:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a id="1" class="edit">E</a>
    <a id="2" class="edit">E</a>
    <a id="2" class="edit">E</a>
</div>

$('.edit').on('click', 'body', function (evt) {
    var thisElement = $(this); // isto é o A que foi clicado
    var id = thisElement.attr('id'); // .attr() retira o atributo que lhe passas
});
```

---

ps: Está ali `'body'` para [`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) porque cheira-me que estás a adicionar elementos dinamicamente. Se isso é verdade, podes:

- a) Agarrar o evento on-click enquanto estás a fazer o `.append()` do html
- b) Fazer event delegation, que é como quem diz: "fazer o hook a um evento que esteja sempre no html enquanto o target é dinamico"

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado. :D

Answer (score 0):

O atributo ID assim como classes, não deve ser iniciado por números, e como aparentemente você precisa do numero ID para selecionar o registro no BD, recomendo que utilize o atributo `data-id` assim:

```js
$('.edit').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

```css
.edit {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: PaleGreen;
  border-radius: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-id="1" class="edit">E</a>
<a data-id="2" class="edit">E</a>
<a data-id="3" class="edit">E</a>
```